# Create typescript definitions for .js files

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and trying to create typescript definition `index.d.ts` for a folder containing javascript files.

```
src
   |--controllers
      |-- index.d.ts
      |-- Controller1.js (myMethod1)
      |-- Controller2.js (myMethod2)
   |--routes
      |-- routes.js
```

Methods in `Controller1` and `Controller2` are generated dynamically. I need to define interface for controllers. i.e. `Controller1` should have `myMethod1` only and `Controller2` should have `myMethod2`.

index.d.ts

```
import * as express from 'express'

interface CommonInterface {
    get(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;

    delete(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;

    update(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;
}

declare namespace Controller1 {
    function myMethod1(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;
}

declare namespace Controller2 {
    function myMethod2(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void;
}
```

Edit: I am importing controllers like below. But code completion shows interface names instead of `myMethod` function.

routes.js

```
const Controller1 = require('../controllers/Controller1');
Controller1.myMethod1() // lint shows unknown method

const Controller1 = require('../controllers'); // index.js
Controller1.Controller1.myMethod1() // lint works correctly here
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @benshabatnoam I've added issue in edit.

Comment: Try to remove `function` in-front of your functions definitions and `declare` in-front of your interface declarations

Comment: Still doesn't work. `Controller1.Controller1.myMethod1()` is shown only.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support type definition. this is a Typescript feature (or [project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), to be precised). This means that you can't see intellisense in your js files using `index.d.ts` file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But this doesn't work. The only way I am able to achieve this is by setting `namespace` and `interface` in .ts file and using `require('../controllers').Controller1` instead.

Comment: That's very strange, check out the demo I've added to my answer to see that this is working... What IDE are U using?

Comment: I am using WebStorm. Demo is using pure `.ts` files. I am working with javascript files

Comment: Wow, I just realized now that you're trying to see the function in a js file (`routes.js`). My bad :(